# Class Factory doesn't exists

Tags: module, blocks, adminhtml, factory, magento-2.2.5

I am after this course
https://www.mage-world.com/blog/grid-and-form-in-magento-2-admin-panel-part-1.html
but my magento version is 2.2.5
so its a little bit different.
i create NewsFactory auto by block instead of controller.
and its throw this err message:[image]

i'm looked on google and stackexchange for 5 hours, but still dont know why this error appear.
so here is my code:
[image]

> app\code\Fudu\HelloWorld\Block\Adminhtml\News.php

```
<?php

namespace Fudu\HelloWorld\Block\Adminhtml;

use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use \Fudu\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Students\Collection as StudentsCollection;
use \Fudu\HelloWorld\Model\Students;
use \Fudu\HelloWorld\Model\NewsFactory;

class News extends Template
{
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     */

    /**
     * News model factory
     * @var null|NewsFactory
     */
    protected $_newsFactory = null;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param NewsFactory $newsFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        NewsFactory $newsFactory,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_newsFactory = $newsFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_news';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'Tutorial_SimpleNews';
        $this->_headerText = __('Manage News');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add News');
    }

    /**
     * @return Students[]
     */

    /** @var StudentsCollection $studentsCollection */
    public function execute()
    {
        $studentsCollection = $this->_newsFactory->create();
        $studentsCollection->addFieldToSelect('*')->load();
        return $studentsCollection->getItems();
    }

    /**
     * For a given students, returns its url
     * @param Students $students
     * @return string
     */
}
```

> app\code\Fudu\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\News.php

```
<?php

namespace Fudu\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class News extends Action
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * Result page factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Registry $coreRegistry,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * News access rights checking
     *
     * @return bool
     */


    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

menu.xml (this is a menu from backend, when we click on the 3rd option, which is "Manage News" , it will redirect to url `simplenews/news/index`).

> app\code\Fudu\HelloWorld\etc\adminhtml\menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Fudu_HelloWorld::main_menu" title="Simple News"
             module="Fudu_HelloWorld" sortOrder="20"
             resource="Fudu_HelloWorld::simplenews" />

        <add id="Fudu_HelloWorld::add_news" title="Add News"
             module="Fudu_HelloWorld" sortOrder="1"
             parent="Fudu_HelloWorld::main_menu"
             action="simplenews/news/new"
             resource="Fudu_HelloWorld::manage_news" />

        <add id="Fudu_HelloWorld::manage_news" title="Manage News"
             module="Fudu_HelloWorld" sortOrder="2"
             parent="Fudu_HelloWorld::main_menu"
             action="simplenews/news/index"
             resource="Fudu_HelloWorld::manage_news" />

        <add id="Fudu_HelloWorld::configuration" title="Configurations"
             module="Fudu_HelloWorld" sortOrder="3"
             parent="Fudu_HelloWorld::main_menu"
             action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/simplenews"
             resource="Fudu_HelloWorld::configuration" />
    </menu>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah i found the answer, it because i need to create a Model after the name of Factory
ex: if u want to create NewsFactory, u will need to create News Model

Comment: Hi, if my answer helped you please give an upvote

Answer (score 0):

If you notice in the screenshot you shared. There is one more News folder under adminhtml. You didn't notice that. So, change

```
namespace Fudu\HelloWorld\Block\Adminhtml
```

to

```
namespace Fudu\HelloWorld\Block\Adminhtml\News
```

Please make sure to clear generated folder and clear the cache.

Also in the same block, there are slashes before class path in 'use' statements. Please remove them.

Change

```
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
```

To

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but my problems is still there .. @@
the factory class doesn't create automatic by block
and i think folder " generated " is not on " var/generated " like the course say, correct?

Comment: Yes, Generated is under root folder not in var